# Does the iPhone SDK include Xcode for Mac OS X development?

Tags: xcode, installation

Does the iPhone SDK include Xcode for Mac OS X development?  Or do I need to install Xcode for Mac separately?

If the latter, does order of installation matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It includes it. It's all the same app (well, the iPhone version is newer, so download a copy, don't install the version that came with your Mac)

Documentation is modular, and you can specify which doc sets you would like to download from inside the IDE.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, I had to install it separately. I might be wrong though...

Comment: You are wrong. The iPhone SDK includes the Xcode IDE and Mac OS X platform support as well.